# How to take alphabetically sorted NSArray into a UITableView sectioned alphabetically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a NSArray `self.objects` which is an array of users.

I'd like to section off the usernames alphabetically into a sectioned `UITableView`.

I took a shot at doing this:

`NSDictionary *usernameDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[self.objects valueForKey:@"username"] forKey:@"usernames"];`

I'm not sure where to go.

UPDATE:

```
 NSMutableSet *mySet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    for (NSString *s in [self.objects valueForKey:@"username"] )
    {
        if ( s.length > 0 )
            [mySet addObject:[s substringToIndex:1]];
    }

    NSArray *indexArray = [[mySet allObjects] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

I've got the section headers to read the letters, and on the side, only issue im having is that each section has the entire array in it. and not specific towards the letter in order

Having a hard time using appcoda's example of numberofrowsinsection:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSString *sectionTitle = [animalSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *sectionAnimals = [animals objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    return [sectionAnimals count];
}
```

Comment: I think you haven't read about section headers of a tableView yet. Please read on that.

Comment: @Joshua I understand how it works, I just don't understand how to create the sections for the perticular letters and then put the correct letters in the correct sections

Comment: @Joshua i updated what i've done so far.

Comment: I think there are so many available  links on how to do this. like for example this link: https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/

Comment: @Joshua I got everything to work, though im stuck at the `numberOfRowsInSection` part. I'm having a hard time translating what to do with my code in respect the the examples. I updated my code up there^

Comment: @Joshua I added their example in my post

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [self.objects sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Now you can create a mutable dictionary where it will add objects as per section i.e one key will contain array of those usernames with same alphabet and the key can be first character of first username with change in alphabet.

Comment: How do i use the array to create the sections?

Comment: no.. I have written the code for sorting of array according alphabet so now put for loop or fast enumeration and add in your dictionary by comparing first character of your previous index name and current index name.. If there is change in name then add it to new key value pair

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018744/turning-an-nsarray-of-custom-objects-into-a-alphabetically-sectioned-uitableview?rq=1

Comment: I tried doing it and it didnt work. Could you give an example?